# Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I try configure GTM for GA account, but I have minor problems.

Screen trigger+tag work almost fine(can't setup secondary dimensions)
Simple Events are not logged

I don't know which couples in "Fields to Set" must be setted. Could  you help me with example?

**Screen handler:**

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
 params.putString("screenName", screenName);
 params.putString("screenID", "LOL");
 getFirebaseAnalytics().logEvent("openScreen", params);
```

[image: GA tags]

[image: screen tag]

[image: screen trigger]

**Event**

```
private void send(String category, String action, String label, int value, String videoPart) {

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("Category", category);
    params.putString("Action", action);
    params.putString("Label", label);
    params.putString("Label", label);
    params.putString("video_part", videoPart);
    params.putInt("Value", value);
    getFirebaseAnalytics().logEvent("event", params);
}
```

[image: event tag]

[image: event trigger]

**variables**

[image: variables]

@eric-burley please help me

**edit**
 D/GAv4: Hit delivery requested: ht=1477299734728, _s=160, _v=ma9.8.77, a=1587067812, 
 aid=com..., an=...DEV, av=1.43.-1, cd2=video_part, 
 cid=9b2a1e0d-ec4d-48b6-87e9-69eafa40887d, ea=Action, ec=Category, el=Label, ev=Value, 
 ni=false, sr=1080x1776, t=event, tid=UA-XXXXXXX-20, ul=eng, v=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your logs it looks like the event is getting logged to Google Analytics by Google Tag Manager. Google Analytics is likely discarding the event because the event value parameter (ev) is [required to be a positive integer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ev). I would try using a numerical constant like 42, or removing the event value parameter.

Do you see any logs from Google Analytics or Google Tag Manager when reporting the screen view? It helps to ensure that both are logging verbosely:
adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
adb shell setprop log.tag.GoogleTagManager VERBOSE

Comment: D/GAv4 - it's debug log from GA. Thank, I already configure GTM. I did a primitive error :)

Comment: and "instant run" from AStudio does not allow a quick fix :)

Comment: do you have example project for FA (like GA:UA-54516992-1) ?